# MySQL GROUP BY behavior (when using a derived table with order by)

Tags: mysql, group-by, derived

Since mysql does not enforce the `Single-Value Rule` (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646121/1688441) does a derived table with an order by guarantee which row values will be displayed? This is for columns not in an aggregate function and not in the `group by`.

I was looking at the question ([MySQL GROUP BY behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645921/mysql-group-by-behavior)) after having commented on and answered the question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653572/1688441) .

I don't agree with the accepted answer, but realized that a possible improved upon answer would be:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM tbl order by timestamp) as tb2
GROUP BY userID;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b475/18

Is this correct though or will mysql still decide arbitrarily which row values will be displayed?

Comment: As a note:  the question you have referred to does not have an accepted answer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24653572/1688441 which you had also answered. It got my thinking on group by behavior. :-)

Comment: As a note.  I do not keep up with MySQL development.  But, they deprecated the automatic ordering for `group by` in version 5.6.  That suggests that they are thinking about adding other algorithms to MySQL, and these might specifically change the behavior of `group by` in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl order by timestamp) as tb2
GROUP BY userID;
```

Relies on a MySQL group by extension, which is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  You are specifically relying on the fact that all the columns come from the same row and the first one encountered.  MySQL *specifically* warns against making this assumption:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are **indeterminate**.

So, you cannot depend on this behavior.  It is easy enough to work around.  Here is an example query:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where not exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.userid = t.userid and t2.timestamp > t.timestamp)
```

With an index on `tbl(userid, timestamp)` this may even work faster.  MySQL does a notoriously poor job of optimizing aggregations.

Comment: "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.". Well that pretty much settles it :-). Thanks.